# How to get route table/acl content using boto?

Tags: boto, amazon-vpc

I'm trying to get the contents of route table and acl like Destination, target...etc using boto. i'm able to fetch the IDs not the content, Please suggest a way to resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

To retrieve the data you need to follow the following steps :

1. First import **VPC CONNECTION** which is 
   `from boto.vpc import VPCConnection`
2. Connect to the **region** you want

> conn=boto.vpc.connect_to_region("ap-southeast-1")

1. Now get all the route tables in an object using the conn object you made. This object will return a list of route tables.

> c=conn.get_all_route_tables()

1. c has objects of class RouteTable , which further has 1 data member of class Route . From that data member you need to retrieve the details :

> for c1 in c:

```
for a in c1.routes:
    print a.destination_cidr_block
    print a.instance_id
    print a.gateway_id
    print a.state
    print a.dry_run
```

If you are getting confused in point 4 , you can see here : http://pydoc.net/Python/boto/2.1.1/boto.vpc.routetable/
Hope it helps !